# Blank Page on Github Pages React App Start

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-pages

I have a react app that runs perfectly on the local port, but when I upload it to github pages through npm I get nothing but a blank screen.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

I receive many 404 errors like these with no clear source. the page built fine, but it doesnt render anything.

heartlocket.github.io/IF

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you reference resources(js, css) using absolute urls, with site route as base url, like `/static/js/main.b9eb92d4.chunk.js`, but your gh-pages actually published to subdirectory `/IF/`, so real location of your resources is like `/IF/static/js/main.b9eb92d4.chunk.js`

You can fix it several ways:

- change all links to relative - i.e. remove leading slash character, like `static/js/main.b9eb92d4.chunk.js`
- add directory to your absolute urls - like `/IF/static/js/main.b9eb92d4.chunk.js`

Comment: i do not even know where those resources are being referenced, it is not anywhere in my code so i assume it has to do with some library. but i am not sure where I would correct those urls

Comment: @HEARTLOCKET, they all referenced just inside your [index.html](https://github.com/heartlocket/IF/blob/gh-pages/index.html) file.

Comment: I am not making any of those references in my index.html and there are no leading spaces in my file